# VB.NET Custom MessageBox in VS designer

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

Seeking for a custom MessageBox that would fulfill my needs and that would resemble the  MessageBox .Net class, still being able to design it via the Visual Studio Form Designer, I came up with this (explanation below the example of code):

```
Public Class CustomMessageBox
    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
    Private Class CustomMessageForm
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

        'Form shadows dispose to clean up the component list.
        <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
        Public Shadows Sub Dispose()
            Try
                If components IsNot Nothing Then
                    components.Dispose()
                End If
            Finally
                MyBase.Dispose(True)
            End Try
        End Sub

        'Required by the Windows Form Designer
        Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

        'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
        'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
        'Do not modify it using the code editor.
        <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
        Private Sub InitializeComponent()
            Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
            Me.SuspendLayout()
            '
            'Button1
            '
            Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(197, 226)
            Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
            Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
            Me.Button1.TabIndex = 0
            Me.Button1.Text = "Button1"
            Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
            '
            'CustomMessageBox
            '
            Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
            Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
            Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 261)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
            Me.Name = "CustomMessageBox"
            Me.Text = "CustomMessageBox"
            Me.ResumeLayout(False)

        End Sub
        Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    End Class

    Public Shared Shadows Function Show(ByVal Title As String) As DialogResult
        Dim dlg As New CustomMessageForm()

        dlg.Text = Title

        Dim res = dlg.ShowDialog

        dlg.Dispose()

        Return res
    End Function
End Class
```

The inner, private, class is the class directly populated by the designer and declared as `Partial` where I modified it to `Private` because my purpose is also to have a Class with (almost) only the Show shared method reachable from outside, just like with the MessageBox .Net class.

I also modified the Dispose method to hide the BaseClass one and to always have it freeing managed resources.

Run-time everything works just fine, but when it comes to modify the form via the designer, as expected, I hit this error:

```
The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: CustomMessageBox --- The base class Object could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.
```

As I said it was expected because the designer I guess is not reaching the inner private class, or for some other reason that I'm not getting into focus at the moment.

Is there a workaround to this and/or some other way to reach the purpose with the same simplicity of code?

Thank you.

P.S.

I'd like to keep the code out from a separate ClassLib by now if possible, and have it as a one .vb file in the same assembly of a Windows Forms Application.

Comment: Your Dialog is a private child class so the IDE cannot use it to perform the layout. `CustomMessageBox` is not a form so you get the message.  Move it all to a ClassLib and treat the `CustomMessageForm` as a form and you should be able to designer layout there

Comment: Exactly as I expected, therefore I was asking for a workaround. After all the WFD is declaring his InitializeComponent as private..... It has to mean something!

Comment: Yes, right, I forgot to mention that I'd like not to make it as a lib by now, if possible. I will add this to the post, Thank you.

Comment: The form need not be an internal class for this to work.  The class can instance the form even when not private; you can even tack all the `CustomMessageBox` code to the end of the Form code if you want to keep them together.  The private Form is the problem, not the number of files

Comment: Right, but if not private I'd be able to reach the CustomMessageForm even from outside the parent class and Im trying to avoid this. I know that I'm asking (too) much, but I'd like to know if I can have all of this together.

Comment: what difference does that make?  `CustomMessageBox` doesnt do much of value anyway.

Comment: Accessibility in .NET is based on the kind of trust you have in the people that can add code to your assembly.  With the blanket assumption that you can trust your friends and your team members but have to be cautious about anybody else.  You therefore can only declare the class *Friend*.  You do so in the main source code file, not the designer file.  If anybody uses your form inappropriately then you'll have very little trouble finding him.

Comment: @Plutonix Did you take a look to the MessageBox .Net class? It does only expose the Show method (and a couple of inheriteds from Object) and nothing more. Alright, I want THAT and the possibility to have WFD for designing without having it in an external class, if possible at all.

Comment: @HansPassant Of course it makes sense.

Comment: @Plutonix After all I guess I will go with the exernal lib and, for that, the friend modifier. If you post your first comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you for the replies.